# phantomjs jasmine jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jasmine, phantomjs

I followed the exact steps given in http://www.zendesk.com/blog/javascript-loves-ci except for jshint (as i do not need it right now). But i am getting the following error when running phantomjs through the runner script. Does anyone have any idea as to why its failing?

```
→ phantomjs spec/javascripts/support/phantom-js-runner.js http://localhost:8888
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
```

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems to fail on some returned objects from inside self executing Function closures...

Answer (score 0):

Most of that setup shouldn't be necessary to get jasmine to run via phantom as of jasmine 2.0. If you install the jasmine-gem, the default runner is now phantom, and we haven't heard of any problems getting it to run.